# Faster way of putting Matrix elements into vectors other than a for loop

Tags: matlab

Hopefully this will come across correctly. I have 4 clouds/groups of points in a grid array (imagine a 2D space with 4 separate clusters of for example 3x3 grid of points) with each point having an X and Y coordinate. I'd like to write a vector of four points in the form of (X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3, X4, Y4) where the number represents each cloud/group. Now I would actually like to write a matrix of all the combinations of the above vector covering all the points, so upper left points in all four groups in the first line, same for the second line, but the top middle point for group 4, etc.

One way to do it is to for-loop over all the variable, which would mean 8 nested for loops (4 for each X coordinate of 4 groups, 4 for each Y coordinate of 4 groups).

Is there a faster way maybe? 4 3x3 groups means 6561 combinations. Going to a larger array in each group, 11x11 for example, would mean 214 million combinations.

I'm trying to parallelize some calculations using these point coordinates, but writing the results in a parfor loop presents it's own set of issues if I was to do it on the points themselves. With a matrix of combinations I could just write the results in another matrix with the same number of rows and write the result of the nth row of point coordinates to the nth row of results.

Comment: Have you tried 'reshape'?

Comment: I think what you want to do is obtain all combinations of drawing 4 numbers from a set of 3x3=9 values with replacement. There is an implementation for example [here](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn).

Comment: @CrisLuengo sounds something that might be useful. You are kind of correct, but not exactly. Each element in the 3x3 matrix actually has two coordinates so each 3x3 point cloud would be a permutation of 3 X and 3 Y coordinates, equaling 9 combinations. Now you need to do another set of permutations for all points over the multiple point clouds.

I'll definitely take a look at it, maybe I can make it work. Thanks!

Maybe write it as an answer? So I can upvote it.

Comment: I wanted to make sure I understood the question correctly before writing an answer. You have a 3x3 matrix where each element is two coordinates, but that still makes 9 elements to choose from (each "element" is a coordinate pair).

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you have 4 groups of 3x3=9 coordinate pairs. You need to draw one pair from each group as one result, and produce all possible such results.

Thus, reducing each of the groups of 9 coordinate pairs to a lookup-table that is indexed with a number from 1 to 9, your problem can be reduced to drawing, with replacement, 4 values from the set `1:9`.

It is fairly easy to produce all such combinations. `permn` is one function that does this (from the [File Exchange](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7147-permn)). But you can actually get these even easier using `ndgrid`:

```matlab
ind = 1:9;
[a1,a2,a3,a4] = ndgrid(ind,ind,ind,ind);
ind = [a1(:),a2(:),a3(:),a4(:)];
```

Each row in `ind` is the indices into one of your 3x3 grids.

For example, if grid 1 is:

```matlab
x1 = [0.5,0.7,0.8];
y1 = [4.2,5.7,7.1];
```

then you can generate the coordinate pairs as follows:

```matlab
[x1,y1] = meshgrid(x1,y1); % meshgrid is nearly the same as ndgrid...
xy1 = [x1(:),y1(:)];
```

Now your combination `k` is:

```matlab
k = 563;
[xy1(ind(k,1),:), xy2(ind(k,2),:), xy3(ind(k,3),:), xy4(ind(k,4),:)]
```

---

You probably want to implement the above using multidimensional arrays rather than `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, etc. Adding indices to variables makes for confusing code that is difficult to extend. For example, for `n` groups you could write:

```matlab
n = 4;
ind = 1:9;
ind = repmat({ind},n,1);
[ind{:}] = ndgrid(ind{:});
ind = cellfun(@(m)reshape(m,[],1), ind, 'UniformOutput',false);
ind = [ind{:}];    % ind is now the same as in the block of code above
```

etc.